# Symfony 1.4 / problem with Doctrine when add new table to schema.yml

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I add two tables to db with this schema:

```
Receiptjob:
 columns:
  charity_id:       integer
  sf_guard_user_id: integer
  created_at:        timestamp
  finished_at:      timestamp
  job_type:         string(32)
  job_status:       integer 
relations:
  User:
    class: sfGuardUser
  Charity:
    class: Charity
  Spende:
    class:     Spende
    refClass:  ReceiptjobMap
    type:      many
    local:     receiptjob_id
    foreign:   spenden_id

 ReceiptjobMap:
   columns:
     receiptjob_id:     integer
     spenden_id:        integer
     spenden_recurring: string(32)
    relations:
      Receiptjob:
        class:        Receiptjob
        local:        receiptjob_id
        foreign:      id
        onDelete:     CASCADE
       Spende:
         class:        Spende
         local:        spenden_id
```

Everything works fine, untill i start my docker container this morning. I get allways this error message:

```
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setTableName() on null in /var/www/vendor/lexpress/doctrine1/lib/Doctrine/Record/Abstract.php:140
```

I'll try to fix error but nothings helps, at least i build a new branch, added my schema.yml again an migrate it, but the error still alive....

what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Symfony 1.4... really? Wow.

Comment: Good luck! You are courageous to work on this Symfony legacy version. :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i was the problem, because i do not call parent::_construct in my class because in the BaseClass was no __construct. But BaseClass extented sfDoctrineRecord, and there is a __construct. So this was the reaseon while setTableName runs on null.